# 2 Classes and Filed in 1 Section

Tags: php

I have 2 different fields in different classes, which are displayed on the site in one section.

**Only one of them is used at a time.**

I am currently using this code:

```
<div class = "class2">
<? php the_sub_field ('filed2'); ?>
</div>
<div class = "class1">
<? php the_sub_field ('filed1'); ?>
</div>
```

Each has a different class, but both options are available. I want to make a condition.

If filed2 is used then class 2
And if filed1 is used then class 1

Right now the style of both is conflicting, and it doesn't fit.
How to define this condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can make as follows :

```
    <? php
    if($field=='field1')
      $class="class1";
    else if($field=='field2')
      $class="class2";


    // here give $field a value 

     $field= 'field1' 
?>

    <div class = " <? php echo $class ?> ">
    <? php the_sub_field ('$field'); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what should be in "here give $ field a value"
Value is obtained from php the_sub_field ('filed2')
And from <? php the_sub_field ('filed1');
Can you send the full code?

Comment: you assign either field1 or field2, depends on what you want.
and then , whatever field you have assigned, the class corresponding to that field (class1 or class2) will be assigned accordingly.

Comment: Each has a different styling, with a different class.
Each time - only one of them is used.
The problem is that an blank Div is noted with Class css style and the style for the blank destroys the view.
Can you send the full code to do this?